# Can I modify equations created by LaTeXiT in Mac Word?

Tags: mactex, msword, latexit

Using LaTeXiT to create an equation and insert in Mac Word is very easy and convenient. However, can I modify the equation I already inserted?

Comment: Droping it back to LaTeXiT should work. Then edit it, and then move it to word again. Not perfect, but should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is stated in the official page:

> Moreover, for the compatible formats, you can reopen the equation to modify it : the LaTeX code is kept inside.

You only need to drop it again in LaTeXiT, edit, and then move back to the document.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Cocoa application which supports Services instead --- TextEdit.app, Pages.app and similar tools will properly provide the Detect and Typeset Equations and Revert Equations back to LaTeX Code commands.

You might be able to save as a .docx, open in one of those tools, revert the equations and then edit and re-typeset them, but w/in Word itself, one can't access capabilities which Microsoft didn't bother to program ('cause of Bill Gates' attitude towards programming for NeXTstep).